# measure the total transmitted byte sent/received in the HttpRequest/Response in servlets

Tags: jsp, servlets, tomcat7

I want to measure the total transmitted bytes for request and response in servlets.

In addition, bytes sent for response and bytes received for request(http get and post methods).

What will be the elegant way to achieve this?

assume, i'm writing to a HTML content output from servlet.In that output, css styles and JavaScript files get involved. How do I get the exact size of bytes sent in the response?

```
StringBuilder htmlcontent = new StringBuilder("");
.append("<!DOCTYPE html><!--[if IE 9]><html class='lt-ie10' lang='en' > <![endif]-->")
                    .append("<html class=\"no-js\" lang=\"en\" >")
                    .append("<head>")                   
                    .append("<title>Sample Page</title>")
                    .append("<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"css/foundation-5.4.css\" />")
                    .append("<script type='text/javascript' src='scripts/app.js'></script>")
                    .append("</head>")
                    .append("<body>")
                    .append("<body>")                   
                    .append("</body>")
                    .append("</html>");

response.getOutputStream().write(htmlcontent).getBytes("UTF-8");
```

Comment: I'd start by implementing a Response wrapper with counting feature, then use a Filter to wrap the standard response with my counting one.

Comment: request.getContentLength(); can be used to get request length

Answer (score 0):

Every container has the support to log web requests. You should be able to log the following:

- request url
- HTTP Method
- Response status code
- Response size
- Request size.

For tomcat here is how you can do,

http://www.techstacks.com/howto/configure-access-logging-in-tomcat.html